# How to properly overlay WMS tiles on google maps? WMS tiles are shifted when overlayed on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, shapefile, qgis, geoserver, wms

I am getting started with GIS.

I am trying to publish a Geography Markup Language (GML) file on geoserver. For this I converted it to a shape file using *ogr2ogr* tool

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" adur.shp adur.gml`

I published the converted Shapefile on geoserver and loaded it in my application as a WMS layer. Here is the jsfiddle link for the below code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/3kmwpsu2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>WMS and Google Maps</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    const EXTENT = [-Math.PI * 6378137, Math.PI * 6378137];

    const xyzToBounds = (x, y, z) => {
      let tileSize = (EXTENT[1] * 2) / Math.pow(2, z);
      let minx = EXTENT[0] + x * tileSize;
      let maxx = EXTENT[0] + (x + 1) * tileSize;
      // remember y origin starts at top
      let miny = EXTENT[1] - (y + 1) * tileSize;
      let maxy = EXTENT[1] - y * tileSize;
      return [minx, miny, maxx, maxy];
    }

    const getWMSTileUrl = (coordinates, zoom) => {
      return (
        "http://wms.prod.qgiscloud.com/abhilash/cloud" +
        "?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0" +
        "&LAYERS=adur" +
        "&FORMAT=image%2Fpng" +
        "&SRS=EPSG:3857&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&TRANSPARENT=TRUE" +
        "&BBOX=" +
        xyzToBounds(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, zoom).join(","))
    };

    function initMap() {
      let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 19,
        center: {
          lat: 50.83238,
          lng: -0.330478
        },
        tilt: 0,
        mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      });

      let layer = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: getWMSTileUrl,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 19,
        opacity: 1.0
      });
      layer.addListener("tilesloaded", () => {
        console.log("Layers loaded")
      });
      map.overlayMapTypes.push(layer);
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I noticed that the boundaries are not aligned properly. I see some shift in the boundaries.

*Note :* *Please note that I used QGIS cloud's WMS link in the demo instead of my local geoserver's WMS URL*

I imported the same shape file into QGIS to check if there is anything wrong with the converted Shapefile. But the borders are aligned properly here. I am attaching both the screenshots below for comparison. You can see that the borders are not aligned properly in the first image. There is some shift here.

I am attaching the GML and converted Shape files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/114hM_4Smbdkd-bWtiWuKSu6ebxr86AU6?usp=sharing) for your reference.

*This screenshot is from my application where the borders are not aligned properly.*
[image: actual]

*This screenshot is from QGIS where borders are aligned properly*
[image: expected]

**UPDATE :**

After several attempts, I added same WMS layer twice in QGIS.

One with *EPSG:4326 - WGS 84* CRS
[image: EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 CRS]

And the other with *EPSG:27700 OSGB36 / British National Grid* - CRS
[image: EPSG:27700 OSGB36 / British National Grid CRS]

This is the result. The WMS layer with EPSG:27700 CRS aligned perfectly.
[image: result]

But I am not able to do the same with GeoServer / in my application. CRS on GeoServer is already in EPSG:27700.

[image: crs on geoserver]

Comment: Is this something regarding wrong projections?

Comment: have you added the NTv2 grid files in both programs

Comment: I did not add NTv2 files. It is working after applying [OSTN 02 NTv2](https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/projections_and_transformations/transformations_in_gdalogr.htm#:~:text=mm_shape%5CTopo_Line_wgs84_7p.shp-,To%20Use%20OSTN02,-To%20use%20the) transformation. So after converting GML to a Shapefile, I applied this transformation using ogr2ogr tool.